# so i have a website running on namecheap cpanel with a domain name and i want another site on aws to use a subdomain from the first one

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, namecheap

`website 1` hosted on namecheap with a domain `www.domainname.org` also bought from namecheap. I want `website 2` which is hosted on aws to have domain name `shop.domainname.org`

i know how to connect a third party domain name to `Route53` on `aws` and setup subdomains but i want to be sure that if I do that through the normal custom dns on namecheap `website 1` would not be affected, or better still if there is anyone with experience on this please give me a step-by-step guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need additional A record on Name cheap. They have it documented very well https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9776/2237/how-to-create-a-subdomain-for-my-domain/